# Windows 7(or XP)'s Network Security Tab Missing

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, permissions, nas

I am setting a local network of windows xp and windows 7 machines, together with a NAS (Synology Diskstation DS209). And then i set up those windows machines so that the users can access the fileserver as a network drive from their "My Computer". And the weird thing is that, when i view the File Properties of any file in the NAS, the Security Tab is missing. However, when i view the local hard drive's File Properties, the Security Tab is right there!

I found some tutorial saying that, in Win XP, i can simply disable simple file sharing to restore the missing Security Tab, but this method failed. And in Windows 7, i tried to access the Local Group Policy Editor but i'm unable to make any change there.

I wonder if it is my NAS(diskstation)'s problem or Windows's problem.

Comment: Is that true of any machine? What file system is the NAS running?

Comment: Yes. the filesystem is NTFS.

Comment: One more point to add. The File Properties Security Tab is available for local hard drives. The security tab just missed in mapped drives.